# How to use a class from different directory in doctrine yaml mapping

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want doctrine yaml mapping file to point to an external class.
My dir structure looks like this:

- src/Core

  - MyExternalClass.php
  - Subdir/MyOtherClass.php
- src/SomeBundle/Resources/config/doctrine

  - MyExternalClass.orm.yml
  - Subdir.MyOtherClass.orm.yml

Can I configure doctrine to look for mapped classes in directory different than "src/SomeBundle/Entity"?

Comment: Read through here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html then comeback if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use custom prefix in doctrine mappings (doctrine.orm.entity_managers...mappings.MyMapping.prefix) to point different namespace.